# Why is RandomAccessFile writeLong implemented with multiple write calls?

Tags: java, performance, io

While profiling an application I noticed that RandomAccessFile.writeLong was taking a lot of time.

I checked the code for this method, and it involves eight calls of the native method write. 
I wrote an alternative implementation for writeLong using a byte[]. Something like this:

```
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("out.dat", "rwd");
...
byte[] aux = new byte[8];
aux[0] = (byte) ((l >>> 56) & 0xFF);
aux[1] = (byte) ((l >>> 48) & 0xFF);
aux[2] = (byte) ((l >>> 40) & 0xFF);
aux[3] = (byte) ((l >>> 32) & 0xFF);
aux[4] = (byte) ((l >>> 24) & 0xFF);
aux[5] = (byte) ((l >>> 16) & 0xFF);
aux[6] = (byte) ((l >>> 8) & 0xFF);
aux[7] = (byte) ((l >>> 0) & 0xFF);
randomAccessFile.write(aux);
```

I made a small benchmark and got these results:

> Using writeLong():
>   Average time for invocation: 91 ms
>
> Using write(byte[]):
>   Average time for invocation: 11 ms

Test run on a Linux machine with a Intel(R) CPU T2300 @ 1.66GHz

Since native calls have some performance penalty, why is writeLong implemented that way? 
I know the question should be made to the Sun guys, but I hope someone in here has some hints.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would vote for laziness, or (being more charitable) not thinking about the consequences.

A native implementation of `writeLong()` would potentially require versions for every architecture, to deal with byte ordering (JNI will convert to platform byte order). By keeping the translation in the "cross-platform" layer, the developers simplified the job of porting.

As to why they didn't convert to an array while on the Java side, I suspect that was due to fear of garbage collection. I would guess that `RandomAccessFile` has changed minimally since 1.1, and it wasn't until 1.3 that garbage collection started to make small object allocations "free".

*But*, there's an alternative to `RandomAccessFile`: take a look at `MappedByteBuffer`

---

Edit: I have a machine with JDK 1.2.2, and this method has not changed since then.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the RandomAccessFile.writeLong() doesn't minimise the number of calls to the OS.  The cost increases dramatically by using "rwd" instead of "rw" which should be enough to indicate its not the calls themselves which cost the time. (its the fact the OS is try to commit every write to disk and the disk only spins so fast)

```
{
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("test.dat", "rwd");
    int longCount = 10000;
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (long l = 0; l < longCount; l++)
        raf.writeLong(l);
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("writeLong() took %,d us on average%n", time / longCount / 1000);
    raf.close();
}
{
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("test2.dat", "rwd");
    int longCount = 10000;
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    byte[] aux = new byte[8];
    for (long l = 0; l < longCount; l++) {
        aux[0] = (byte) (l >>> 56);
        aux[1] = (byte) (l >>> 48);
        aux[2] = (byte) (l >>> 40);
        aux[3] = (byte) (l >>> 32);
        aux[4] = (byte) (l >>> 24);
        aux[5] = (byte) (l >>> 16);
        aux[6] = (byte) (l >>> 8);
        aux[7] = (byte) l;
        raf.write(aux);
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("write byte[8] took %,d us on average%n", time / longCount / 1000);
    raf.close();
}
```

prints

```
writeLong() took 2,321 us on average
write byte[8] took 576 us on average
```

It would appear to me that you have no disk write caching on.  Without disk caching, I would expect each commited write to take about 11 ms for a 5400 RPM disk ie 60000 ms/5400 => 11 ms.

Comment: It should be MUCH faster for both of them.  Can you try my test code which is in micro-second?

Comment: In my tests I'm also using the 'd' flag. This makes writes synchronous, making writes a lot slower.

Comment: You can usually get two out of three of these; performance, reliability, low price.  Its is very hard to get all three. ;) At a certain point you reach a limit of what your hardware can do. I suggest you work out what that is and program around it.

Comment: I know that. My question was because of the way writeLong is implemented. For example, if I use "rw" I get 20us using  writeLong and only 4us when I'm using write(byte[]). This shows that the multiple native calls done by writeLong have some impact that could be avoided in my point of view

Comment: @Peter - reducing calls to the OS is unlikely, since `write` makes an OS call each time it happens (RAF does not do any buffering itself)